# How to total of the prime numbers for both threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Now I have two thread, first thread number is 5,7 and second thread number is 11,13.

I want to total up the number of thread like 5+7+11+13 but I not have idea to total up these number because when I try to total up there just only like 5+7=11(it from one threads only).

So how I can total up from both threads?

What I have try :

```
public class MyThread {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //input from user
        System.out.print("Please input x: ");
        int start = sc.nextInt();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(()->sayHello(start));
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(()->number(start));
        t2.start();


    }
    public static void sayHello(int start){
        {
            int count;
            //loop for finding and printing all prime numbers between given range
            for (int i = start; i <= start+5; i++) {
                //logic for checking number is prime or not
                count = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                        count = count + 1;
                }
                if (count == 2)
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i);

                }
            //closing scanner class(not mandatory but good practice)
           // sc.close();
        }
    }

    public static void number(int start) {

        {
            //scanner class object creation

            int count;
            //loop for finding and printing all prime numbers between given range
            for (int i = start+5; i <=start+10; i++) {
                //logic for checking number is prime or not
                count = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                        count = count + 1;
                }
                if (count == 2)
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":" + i );
            }
         
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: There is a concept of wait in the thread......please read It first.

Comment: can show example like how type this code because I cannot  understands it

Comment: 5+7=11? That doesn't sound right. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will share a solution which is done by busy waiting. To improve it you can check [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) structure. It returns 36 as sum.

```
package training;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyThread {

  private static int sumOfThreads;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // input from user
    System.out.print("Please input x: ");
    int start = sc.nextInt();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> sayHello(start));
    t1.start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> number(start));
    t2.start();

    while (t2.isAlive() || t1.isAlive()) { // Busy waiting
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sumOfThreads);
  }

  synchronized private static void addIntoSum(int input) {
    sumOfThreads += input;
  }

  public static void sayHello(int start) {
    {
      int count;
      // loop for finding and printing all prime numbers between given range
      for (int i = start; i <= start + 5; i++) {
        // logic for checking number is prime or not
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          if (i % j == 0)
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 2) {
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i);
          addIntoSum(i);
        }
      }
      // closing scanner class(not mandatory but good practice)
      // sc.close();
    }
  }

  public static void number(int start) {

    {
      // scanner class object creation

      int count;
      // loop for finding and printing all prime numbers between given range
      for (int i = start + 5; i <= start + 10; i++) {
        // logic for checking number is prime or not
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          if (i % j == 0)
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 2) {
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i);
          addIntoSum(i);
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any busy waiting in this solution. You are simply using a lock.

Comment: while (t2.isAlive() || t1.isAlive()) is forcing to wait until threads are completed. If we ignore this part, we print the sum in a moment before a thread completed. Therefore, the result will be wrong.

Comment: Oh, that! I think using `Thread.join()` would be the more appropriate way to wait for the threads to finnish.

Comment: I using this code ,but return the sum as wrong..So how to fix it

Comment: @UlaLee are you sure you have tested the whole code? it prints correctly.

Comment: Yes ,but it not print 36 as sum. It prints 69 as sum .So how to do it correct?

Comment: So sorry ,just now I try again and copy all codes from you. It returns right sum . It is my fault to put the code. Thank for helping me